# Connection string for a remote SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-connection, connection-string

I am trying to connect to a remote SQL server. I would like to know the proper way to connect to the server. TCP/IP protocol is enabled. I am trying this way:

```
@"Server=myserver.com\SQLEXPRESS; Database=mydatabase; User ID=user; password=pass"
```

I am using `myserver.com` to connect to the server via RDP and I can connect without any problems, but when I am using the combination above to connect
to the SQL server via my code, it says that the server can't be found or does not exist.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I introduce you to http://www.connectionstrings.com whenever I have to manually create a connection string that's my first port of call. I can tell you right now that you can't do SQLExpress from a remote client (at least not the last time I checked). But [here](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) is the page for SQL Server connection strings. If it works, then it'll be there

**Edit**
It looks like you *can* connect remotely. It's just not configured that way [out of the box](http://datamasker.com/SSE2005_NetworkCfg.htm)